# How to resolve CERIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error in get_token for EventHubConsumerClient in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to create a EventHubConsumerClient using TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET. Here is my sample code. However I always get a warning:
like this:

*2021-09-27:16:56:39,92 WARNING  [get_token_mixin.py:get_token] ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)
2021-09-27:16:56:39,98 WARNING  [decorators.py:wrapper] EnvironmentCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)*

```
        os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"] = tenantId
        os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"] = client_id
        os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"] = client_secret

        credential = EnvironmentCredential()

        self.client = EventHubConsumerClient(fully_qualified_namespace,
                                             eventhub_name,
                                             consumer_group=group,
                                             credential=credential,
```

http_proxy=self.HTTP_PROXY, ssl_verify=True)

I know that my tenantId, clientId and secret are correct because I am able to do a post request and get a token. However to create a client, our solution does not return a connection_string and hence I have to do clientid authentication: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/client_identity_authentication.py

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused either by server configuration or Python configuration.

If your z/OSMF was configured with self signed certificate, the python3 output error is:
**certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain**

The default value for parameter verify is True. Python 3.6+ installer has its own default certificate store for verifying SSL connections. The system certificate store will not be used any more. To use default certificate store, python library certifi must be installed in advance.

You can use command "pip3 install certifi" to install it.
Python default certificate store was in cacert.pem file, you can get it by

```
import certifi
certifi.where()
        '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'
```

For more information refer to the [community blog](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ibmz-and-linuxone/blogs/sheng-jie-han/2021/06/03/how-to-fix-certificate-verify-failed-self-signed-c)